# better way to check if a value is inside of a nested array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm working with Google Places API. I noticed when I enter establishment not always have a zipcode, country, city and if they do they aren't always in the same index inside the address_components array.

Now, I'm trying to find if it has any of the things listed above, and if it does return the value. Is there a better way to achieve this:

```
getPlaceTypeValue(addressComponents: Places[], type: string): string {
    let value = null;
    for (const [i] of addressComponents.entries()) {
      if (addressComponents[i].types.includes(type)) {
        value = addressComponents[i].long_name;
        break;
      }
    }
    return value;
  } 
console.log(this.placesService.getPlaceTypeValue(
address.address_components, 'postal_code'));
//Returns 77500
```

**Data**

```
[
      {
        "long_name": "Hotel Zone",
        "short_name": "Hotel Zone",
        "types": [
          "sublocality_level_1",
          "sublocality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Kukulcan Boulevard",
        "short_name": "Kukulcan Boulevard",
        "types": [
          "neighborhood",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Cancún",
        "short_name": "Cancún",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Quintana Roo",
        "short_name": "Q.R.",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Mexico",
        "short_name": "MX",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "77500",
        "short_name": "77500",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would change this:

```
for (const [i] of addressComponents.entries()) {
  if (addressComponents[i].types.includes(type)) {
```

to this:

```
for (const {types} of addressComponents) {
  if (types.includes(type)) {
```

Or if you like a more *functional* approach, then use `Array#find` in a one-line `return` statement:

```
return (addressComponents.find(({types}) => types.includes(type)) || {}).long_name || null;
```

The `|| null` part is only needed if a return value of `undefined` would not be OK for you.

#### Speed

If in your question "better" means "faster", then go for the old-school `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0, len = addressComponents.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (addressComponents[i].types.includes(type)) {
```

Comment: Holy s**t very cool. Can you explain me this part ```const {types}```  and now which solution is faster ?

Comment: `{types}` is destructuring, much like `[i]` is also destructuring, but it does so from a different iterator. You took `.entries()`, which in fact gives you pairs of [index, value], and of which you take only the index. I took instead the array itself as iterable, which  only gives the values (objects). And with those I use destructuring to take out the type. If speed is your concern, then nothing beats the old-school `for` loop (until engines better optimise the newer constructs).

Comment: Speed is not a concern in this case, since the set of data is always going to be very small, by better way i meant a smarter way and your answer was great. I learned new things on JS.  Am I right on this... ```types.includes(type)) || {}``` if true return an object, if not return ```{}``` and if it returns ```{}```, then ```{}.long_name``` will be ```undefined``` and if its ```undefined``` it will return ```null```

Comment: Yes, you got that right. There is one "gotcha", if ever the `long_name` is an empty string, then you'll also get a `null`. It would be better to use `undefined` as the return value of your function, and just skip that `null`.